# Form submit html and js

Tags: javascript, html, forms

After checking with recaptcha I want to send info to another page. If I print in the console the info they are visible but if I send that and I get by post they are undefined

```js
var payload = {
  name: '<?php echo $name ?>',
  email: '<?php echo $email ?>'
};
console.table(payload);
var form = document.createElement('form');
form.style.visibility = 'hidden'; // no user interaction is necessary
form.method = 'POST'; // forms by default use GET query strings
form.action = 'test.php';
for (key in Object.keys(payload)) {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.name = key;
  input.value = payload[key];
  form.appendChild(input); // add key/value pair to form
}
document.body.appendChild(form); // forms cannot be submitted outside of body
form.submit(); // send the payload and navigate
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are printing in the console is not the same as what you are inserting into the form.

`Object.keys` gives you an **array** containing the keys from an object.

`key in` loops over the keys of an object.

Looking over the keys of an array gives you `0`, `1`, etc.

`payload[key]` then gives you `payload[0]` and `payload[1]` which are undefined.

---

Either loop over `key in payload` or use `Object.keys(payload).forEach(...)` (or `Object.entries(payload).forEach` since you want the keys and values anyway).

Answer (score 0):

`for ... in` already loops over the keys, so `key` becomes `0` and `1`, but of course `payload[0]` is `undefined`. I'd recommen using `Object.keys(payload).forEach(...)` instead:

```js
var payload = {
  name: '<?php echo $name ?>',
  email: '<?php echo $email ?>'
};
console.table(payload);
var form = document.createElement('form');
//form.style.visibility = 'hidden'; // no user interaction is necessary
form.method = 'POST'; // forms by default use GET query strings
form.action = 'test.php';
Object.keys(payload).forEach((key) => {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.name = key;
  input.value = payload[key];
  form.appendChild(input); // add key/value pair to form
});
document.body.appendChild(form); // forms cannot be submitted outside of body
//form.submit(); // send the payload and navigate
```

I removed the `visibility: hidden` so we can actually see what happens in the form. Before the change to `forEach()`, the inputs contained `undefined`, so that would already have pointed to the issue being getting the correct values from `payload`.